# chrome.tabs.onCreated and executescript for Chrome Extensions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to execute some script inside another external page off of a new tab listener.

background.js

```
function onCreatedChrome(){
    chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
        if (tab.url.indexOf("chrome-devtools://") == -1) {
            localStorage.setItem("tabid", tab.id);
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "alert('Hello World')"}, function() {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    localStorage.setItem("Error", chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                    console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                }
                else{
                    localStorage.setItem("Else case", "This should work")
                }
            });
        }
    });
}


function createTab(){
    return function(){
        var url = "https://www.yahoo.com/";
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: url });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    onCreatedChrome();
    $("#button").click(createTab());
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Execute Script",
  "description": "ExecuteScript extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://www.yahoo.com/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background":{
    "scripts": ["background.js", 
                "jquery.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <button id="button">Click Me</button>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</html>
```

I want the`alert('Hello World')`to be injected into Yahoo!'s homepage (This is just an example of what I am trying to do in another extension)

Comment: Can we get the details of what is wrong?  Maybe an error message or description of unexpected behavior beyond "it doesn't work"?

Comment: What should happen is a new tab is created which opens Yahoo!'s homepage and an alert js should be injected (everytime I click the extension's button) but this does not occur. It seems like the JS is not injected into the Yahoo! tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is becuase you added **jQuery.js** after the **background.js** file
Here is the fix:

```
"background":{
    "scripts": ["jquery.js",
                "background.js"]
  },
```

**Another alternative for the executeScrit task:**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status != 'complete')
        return;
    if (tab.url.indexOf('yahoo.com') != -1) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            code: 'alert(1)'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!..but unfortunately it doesn't work =/

Comment: Can you please check the extension console log for me ?

Comment: There is nothing there =/

Comment: Hmm.. I need more information, want to try a TeamViewer conf?

Comment: I have zipped my code here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nlmdquhhe70px2l/ExecuteScriptBug.zip?dl=0)

Comment: You cant use jQuery inside background.js

Comment: Erase everything and update with the code of my answer and you should be fine!

Comment: Just curious, why can't I use jQuery in the background page?

Comment: Sorry, you actualy can use jQuery. i did some research. I will update my answer.

Comment: I think its key that jquery is the first one thats listed, not sure why that is. Thanks though! It works

Comment: Great! =) If you have any other questions feel free to ask ^_^