# Chrome Console/Extensions: Visit a URL and click a button. Rinse and repeat for a different URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

INITIAL QUESTION:

Is it possible to run javascript from Chrome's Console that will:

1. Navigate to a given URL
2. Click a button

I'd like to repeat the above steps for hundreds of URLs.
I'm sure if I get the two steps working iterating over a number of URLs will be fairly straightforward.

So, I've made Console persistent between page refreshes, so that's a good start...but it seems the Click event it not being triggered.
The clicking command works fine if I manually navigate to the URL then run it via Console, but not as a whole piece of code.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
function f() {
window.location.href = "https://mywebsite.com/post"; 
document.querySelector('.post_like_button_class').click(); 
     }
f();
```

---

EDIT:
One of the commenters below suggested using Chrome Extensions to achieve that. This is what I have written so far:

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Getting Started Example",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Build an Extension!",
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "images/get_started32.png",
"default_title": "Your title"
},
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": false
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://www.google.com" });
});
```

Now...how do I then carry out the second part of my task? I'm a bit stuck.

Click a button:

```
document.querySelector('.post_like_button_class').click();
```

Comment: You can do it with `Chrome extensions`

Comment: @DananjayaAriyasena I'd like to do this process for hundreds of different posts on the website. Would Chrome Extension handle this? i.e. click one on the Extension, the extension would go through a list of URLs and click a button on each page? thanks

Comment: Yes, you can. you can do so many things.

Comment: You can do so many things in chrome extensions. check this link [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyhu42WSC6Y&t=32s]

Comment: @DananjayaAriyasena Thank you for the suggestion. I can see that you do a lot of work with chrome extensions. I'm totally new and trying to figure this out. It doesn't seem like this should be more than putting on js file somewhere though no? I don't really need any html and json thing should be minimul. Got any suggestion for a js script? thanks

Comment: You are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850092/chrome-tabs-oncreated-and-executescript-for-chrome-extensions-not-working I think

Comment: @maxpaj not quite but thank you. I've now found the answer, see below.

Answer (score 1):

After some further digging, here's one way to do it:

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Getting Started Example",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Build an Extension!",
"permissions": [ "*://*/*"
                ],
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "images/get_started32.png",
  "default_title": "Your title"
 },
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": true
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.update({ url: "https://www.instagram.com/p/Bk6AGDQFqvn/" });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.active) {

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,   
{code:" <INSERT YOUR JS CODE HERE> "});                                 
 }
})
```

Comment: Finally, you have started extension development. keep it up.