# Chrome console: navigate to a webpage and click a button after it loads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I can write Javascript in the Chrome console that navigates to an arbitrary URL and loads it.

I can also use setTimeout to wait 5000 ms before clicking a button.

But I can't put those two things together to click a button on a page that is not yet loaded at the time of execution.

```
// Test for page-to-page navigation
this.document.location = "https://www.someform.com";

setTimeout( function() {
document.querySelector('body > div.container > form > input:nth-child(2)').click()
}, 5000);
```

I see that [it can be done with Chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272483/chrome-console-extensions-visit-a-url-and-click-a-button-rinse-and-repeat-for), but I need to do this from Chrome console (and other browser consoles, due to pages that I navigate restricting which browser I use).

I've written many NodeJS scripts that accomplish this using the NightmareJS package, but it uses the Electron browser, which is no good when I need to test with Internet Explorer or a different browser.

Comment: Not possible since it is a new page and anything after it will not run.

Comment: ^^ That.  The script you execute will no longer exist because of a new Url loading.  The *only* way to do this is with an extension.  You could, however, look at what the button click does and look at mimicking it without the page.

Comment: If you can explain the use case there may be simpler or alternative solution.

Comment: Why does this have to be done in a browser console? You could do this easily with something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org).

Comment: It's mainly for testing on sites that require a specific browser like IE - I'm also slightly curious about it. Like I was saying with NightmareJS, it uses a browser called Electron, so I don't think that will work on websites with specific browser policies. I would guess that PhantomJS and Selenium work the same way, but I will check them out.

Answer (score 0):

How about just running the code on an interval, and checking if the button exists before attempting to click it?

```
setInterval(() => {
  const button = 
      document.querySelector('body > div.container > form > input:nth-child(2)');
  if (button) {
    button.click();
  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Like the previous comments said, it's going to be impossible to load the page and then click the button, so the button would never exist in your example.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. So you want to use JS to navigate to a page, and then run the code to click the button. There are ways in DevTools to pause the code pretty close to initial page load. From there you could run the code in DevTools while paused in order to click the button. If that works for you I can update my answer to describe how to do it.

Comment: Yeah, if those steps can all be done in sequence without any user / developer manual actions between each step. If not, just say in your answer that it can't be done and then describe it as a pretty-close workaround.